# Vaadin 8 combobox implements before(!) dropdown event?

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

Is it possible in Vaadin 8 combobox handle before(!) dropdown event?

Actually, I need to implement `DataProvider` that would re-read data each time when a user tries to select data from the combobox (adding new items are not allowed). `CallbackDataProvider`, `FetchItemsCallback` etc. are not an option cause they read data only once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing `AbstractBackEndDataProvider`? Method `fetchFromBackEnd` seems to be called every time user opens the combo box.

Furthermore the is enhanced version of the ComboBox in the Vaadin's Directory https://vaadin.com/directory/component/prefixcombobox, which adds events for observing popup opening and closing. But this event is fired after popup has been opened.